# Android ViewHolder Background Color

Tags: android

I am creating an Android application that contains a RecyclerView with a nested CardView.  I need to alternate every other Card to a different color.  I am using `@Override` to override the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder vh, int pos)` method.  I need to change the background color from that method (I assume), but there are no methods to set the background color of a ViewHolder!

I'm sorry for my noobie-ness, I'm learning Android development now.

-Ben

EDIT: Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_9);

    pieRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    pieRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    pies = makePies();

    pieLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    pieRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(pieLayoutManager);
    PieAdapter adapter = new PieAdapter(pies);
    pieRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class PieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Pie> mPies;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public PieAdapter(ArrayList<Pie> pies) {

        mPies = pies;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Pie currentPie = mPies.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(currentPie.mName);
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(currentPie.mDescription);
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        String price = formatter.format(currentPie.mPrice);
        holder.textViewPrice.setText(price);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mPies.size();

    }
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textViewName;
    public TextView textViewDescription;
    public TextView textViewPrice;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {

        super(v);
        textViewName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
        textViewPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);

    }
}

private ArrayList<Pie> makePies() {

    ArrayList<Pie> pies = new ArrayList<Pie>();
    pies.add(new Pie("Apple", "An old-fashoned favorite.", 1.5));
    pies.add(new Pie("Blueberry", "Made with fresh Maine blueberries.", 1.5));
    pies.add(new Pie("Cherry", "Delicious and fresh made daily", 2.0));
    pies.add(new Pie("Coconut Cream", "A customer favorite.", 2.5));
    return pies;

}

private class Pie {

    String mName;
    String mDescription;
    double mPrice;

    public Pie(String name, String description, double price) {

        this.mName = name;
        this.mDescription = description;
        this.mPrice = price;

    }
}`
```

Comment: post some code to see how you're implementing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ViewHolder` object is not itself a `View`. If you want to change the background of the entire list item, you probably want to call `viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(...)`. The `itemView` of a `ViewHolder` is whatever `View` you passed into the constructor.

Comment: Is there a way to grab the Card that is being worked with?  I would like to set the entire card background color.

Comment: Assuming there's a `CardView` as part of your `itemView` layout, you could add  to the `ViewHolder` the exact same way you've added your `TextView`s.

Comment: How can I get the `View` from the `ViewHolder`?  I can change the TextViews on the ViewHolder, but can't change the background color.  What am I missing?!

Comment: As I said, it's the `itemView` instance inside your `ViewHolder`.

Comment: So when I use the `itemView` in my `holder.itemView`, it changes the color behind the card.  The card is not changing background color.  Is there a way to access the card in the view.  Is it as simple as `findViewById(R.id.card_view)`?

Comment: And it is.  So the `itemView` will return the view that was passed with the `ViewHolder`?  If so, does this work with any type of element?

Comment: Yes. As I said, the `itemView` of a `ViewHolder` is whatever `View` you passed into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `RecyclerView.Adapter` is a generic class defined thusly:

```
public class RecyclerView.Adapter<VH extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

You will create your own subclass of `ViewHolder` that has private variables for references to the child views in your item view.  Then you will define your adapter subclass something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>
```

The idea is that during `onCreateViewHolder()` when you create your `ViewHolder` subclass, you will also inflate a view and store references to the child views in private variables.  That's what makes it a view *holder*, you get and store references to all the child views.

Then, when `onBindViewHolder()` is called, you get the position to determine the data to put into those views.

Keep in mind that the `RecyclerView` only calls `onCreateViewHolder()` when it doesn't have any `ViewHolder`s to recycle.

Comment: So how do I go about changing properties of the ViewHolder?  Do I need to do it elsewhere in the class?

Comment: Another wording: how can I access the view that the TextView on the card is located on?  If there is a TextView on a card, I would like to get that view's view and change that view's background color.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Your `ViewHolder` subclass will have a private `TextView` field that you set after you create an instance in `onCreateViewHolder()`.  Then in `onBindViewHolder()`, you access the `TextView` field to set the background.